MS Access query - Error: The database engine could not lock table ' ' because it is already in use by another person or process
I am not a frequent Access user and have limited experience. I have a tool I am updating in Visual Studio that runs a schema update for users personal Access DBs. It seems that the portion of the query that is moving one column from one table to another is "keeping hold" of the table after the join. It fails when it attempts to run the next portion of the query to remove the original column. I have confirmed (many times) that the table is not being used by anyone or anything else so this join seems to be the culprit.
Here is the query I am running:
UPDATE PROPERTY A
LEFT JOIN PROPERTY2 B ON A.[PROPNUM] = B.[PROPNUM]
SET A.[LATERAL]=B.[LATERAL];
ALTER TABLE PROPERTY2
DROP COLUMN [LATERAL];
The error comes back as:
Failed Command: ALTER TABLE PROPERTY2 DROP COLUMN [LATERAL];
I have tested this function many times in Access itself and it seems the only way to move the column and it's data is to use the join. I need to find a way to "release" the join to continue the operation of dropping the original column.
